# How many times can you divide a list of n elements in 1/2

Tags: recurrence-relation, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to wrap my head around recursion and divide and conquer algorithms. Can someone provide a proof and explanation of how many times a list of n elements can be divided in 1/2 on both sides.. In other words the total number of half divisions in a recursive divide procedure on a list of size n.

Comment: Have you tried some examples?  Have you read through standard textbook descriptions of divide-and-conquer?  What have you done to try to solve your own problem?  We expect you to make a serious effort to try to solve your problem on your own, first, before asking here, and we expect you to show us what you've tried in the question.  In this case, you'd probably find it very helpful to work out a few small examples by hand.

Comment: @D.W. I am reading Kleinberg and Tardos Algorithm Design. IMHO, the book glosses over recursion and divide and conquer. This proof is not a homework assignment. From all my reading, I can only seeme to determine that the number of levels in log(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that the base case in the recursive division procedure is a list of only 1 element.

You mentioned that division is done on both sides. So it turns out that there is no need to think in terms of recursive division. This is because no matter what the procedure is, you end up sub-dividing until there is only 1 element.

So a similar question will be: how many times can we divide a list of n elements into its single elements? Well we do this every day, and we do this **n-1** times!

Comment: Touche! I see how this works now.

Comment: We are usually interested in the recursion depth rather than the number of leaves.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't explained what "divide in half" means, but let's assume that it means to divide the list into two halves of as equal size as possible (equal if the number of elements is even, almost equal if it's odd).

You can draw recursive "division in half" as a tree. The root is labelled by the original number of vertices, $n$. A node labelled $1$ is a leaf. Any other node labelled $m > 2$ has two children labelled $\lfloor m/2 \rfloor$ and $\lceil m/2 \rceil$ (this is the "division in half"). As yemelitc shows in their answer, the number of leaves is $n-1$; this is irrespective of the division being "in half". On the other hand, the *depth* of the tree (number of edges in longest path from root to leaf) is $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$. You can try to prove this in the case where $n = 2^k$ (you can use induction on $k$).